# How to get std::thread of current thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

How can I get a `std::thread` object representing current (already running thread).

I know I can do `std::this_thread::get_id()`. However, this will give me a `std::thread:id` object.

My main goal is to allow some other thread to join current one. However, the problem is that current one wasn't started by creation of std::thread, so I couldn't have saved it beforehand.

Comment: Imagine you *could* get a reference to yourself, and you called `this_thread().join()`...

Comment: Functionality of `std::thread` you can perform on your current thread: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/

Comment: You can't call "join" on the current thread because you'd be joining on yourself as Kerrek points out.

Comment: It sounds like the OP wants to pass the a reference to the `std::thread` object of the current thread *to another thread* so that the latter can perform the joining, though.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If the same author controls the source code for both threads, then `join()` is not the only way in which one thread can wait for another to complete its work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't get a `std::thread` object referring to a thread that wasn't created by the `std::thread` constructor. Either consistently use the C++ thread library, or don't use it at all. If the current thread was created by `pthread_create`, for example, it will need to be joined to using `pthread_join`.

Comment: What's inconsistent about wanting an `std::thread` of the current thread?

Comment: @einpoklum look at [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262750/how-to-get-stdthread-of-current-thread#comment71682985_42262750). That is, a *deadlock*.

Comment: @einpoklum The inconsistency is that the OP wanted a `std::thread` object for the current thread *that was not started using the `std::thread` constructor*. If he wanted a `std::thread` object for the current thread that *was* started using the `std::thread` constructor then my answer would have been different (this is not supported because it violates the rule that only one `std::thread` object can refer to any one thread).

Comment: @ローウ There's nothing inconsistent about constructing a std::thread from a os-specific thread handle (which is already exposed elsewhere on the object). And if from a thread handle, then also completely consistent to construct a thread from the current thread handle. The self-join argument is fatuous because there's nothing stopping a thread constructed with std::thread from joining itself either. One of the most tedious things about C++ "It's inconsistent to do it for no other reason than they didn't do it". A language cursed by its language committee.

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread` is not copy able. Being able to arbitrarily get a thread without getting the resources  from initial creation would break how the thread is supposed to work.

Any reference to a thread should be or have been moved from the object that the constructor was called on.

Comment: Your argument would work for std::jthread, but doesn't work for thread, since the internal thread handle doesn't get closed/joined by std::thread::~thread().  What "how it's supposed to work" gets broken? This is just post-rationalization of a bad decision made by the standards committee.

Comment: @RobinDavies you have a lot to say about the committee and the answers to this question, why not just supply your own answer?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code uses std::thread to start the "other thread", that wants to join() the "current thread"

If the "current thread" is the main thread, i.e. the one started by main(), you cannot make it a std::thread() instance, for good reasons (e.g. if main thread exits, the entire process exits). You should not have other thread join main thread anyway.

If the "current thread" is created from your own code, then you should change it to use std::thread.

If the "current thread" is created from third party library, then you should use the same threading implementation as exposed by third party library. Normally if the third party library expects you to "join()" their thread, they would have exposed a join() method to you, or indicate that you should use specific thread implementation API (e.g. POSIX thread) to join.

Either way, it seems that for good reasons, you cannot do what you wanted.

Comment: The very bad reason being that you can't use a common type to encapsulate  std::thread's and threads coming from other sources. The "bad reason" far outweighs the "good reason" (which isn't really good. I wish people could just say ""you can't do it", and leave it at that. (And maybe leave a brief curse for the language committee that left an obvious use-case out).