# How do I get the native handle of the current thread, with standard C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread

I know  about [`std::this_thread::get_id()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/get_id), and about [`std::thread::native_handle()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle). But - the latter is a method of `std::thread`, while the former gets you an ID - and you [can't construct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) an `std::thread` from an `std::thread::id`.

So - how can I otherwise "combine" these two and get the current thread's native handle, a-l-a `pthread_self()`?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262750/how-to-get-stdthread-of-current-thread

Comment: You can't get a `std::thread` for the calling thread. You will have to use platform specific APIs directly, like `GetCurrentThread()` on Windows and `pthread_self()` on POSIX.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You mean, I can't with standard C++11?

Comment: See Howard Hinnant's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259257/c11-native-handle-is-not-a-member-of-stdthis-thread)