# How do I get a reference to the std::thread object that is current

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, new-operator, allocation

I want to create my own thread class based upon std::thread. My class will have an allocator for dynamic memory. For this the operator new function must obtain a reference to the current thread. How to get this reference and does this work fast?

Comment: AFAIK not every thread has a `std::thread`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262750/how-to-get-stdthread-of-current-thread for a potential duplicate.

Comment: Note that [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) is not polymorphic, so I suggest you don't use inheritance for your thread class.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your responses, and I was too fast in asking this question. I solved the problem myself, I can pass the address of the thread like:

Comment: std::thread mythread1(foo,&mythread1);

Comment: ...and as for the std::thread class is not polymorphic: I am not intending to override any member functions of std::thread, just adding functionality